# What is Profit Ratio in BTC.com mining calculator

Tags: mining-profitability

BTC.com website has a sophisticated Bitcoin mining profitability calculator and a simple calculator. The sophisticated one has a lot of settings.

There is a particular setting named "profit ratio" which is a percent.

I experimented with it and found that when this is equal to 100% the income is computed exactly correct and when I increase it the income is increased by that amount of percent. For example in 110% the income is calculated 10% more.

The default value is 102%.

What is the use of this setting?

https://btc.com/tools/mining-calculator

[image: BTC.com mining calculator]